# OctoberCMS -> Access to a different Pages->Content Tab

Tags: laravel, twig, octobercms

i have a small problem. I created a partial that gives me out all pages. Now i want to give out the Content from the different Pages. All pages have a tab that named "Image", but i don't know how access to

---

### Layout

```
{% for child in page.getChildren %}
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <span>
            <!-- Here the Content of the Tab "Image" -->
        </span>                        
        <a href="{{ child.url|app }}">
            ClickMe
        </a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

---

### Page

[image: Click for the Preview]

So can you help me to access to the right Tab? I already tried these one (but i only can access to the content tab)

```
{{ child.content }}
```

this doesn't worked for me

```
{{ child.Tab.Image }}
```

or

```
{{ child.Image }}
```

Comment: How did you get the tab there?

Comment: i created this in the Layout         {% placeholder Image %}

Comment: Are you wanting to attach an image to each link?

Answer (score 0):

If you use placeholder, you can only insert text in backend newly created tab. The best way to create an image custom field in your page (I assume that you are using Static Pages plugin, like you photo suggests) is use this syntax:

```
{variable name="image" label="Image" tab="The name of your tab here" type="mediafinder" mode="image"}{/variable}
```

Remember to put this code in you layoutfile.

You can find all of your needs in plugin's documentation [here](https://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-pages) and [here](http://octobercms.com/docs/services/parser#dynamic-syntax-parser).
Remember that you can use all of OctoberCMS's built in form fields (yeah, also repeater!)